# Complex numeric string extraction

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have data frame containing a list of orders which, unfortunately, have the item's cost concatenated into the string e.g.

```
1 First aid training for 226.80 GBP
```

I was wondering how I can extract the item cost from such a list. In the above example: 226.80. I'm familiar with using `gsub` and/or `str_detect` but I don't know how to extract when the length of the number string changes length (e.g. 5 characters long for 226.50 but 8 characters long for 37654.90). Note that I need to drop the first number in the above string (i.e. '1'). I only need to keep the numbers prior to the string GBP.

Here is a short dataframe which I hope will cover all situations if someone can help me write the appropriate code.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), item = c("1 First aid training for 226.80 GBP", "3 books for 2.80 GBP", "5 laptops for 2126.80 GBP",  "145 sandwiches for 342.10 GBP", "1 car for 37654.90 GBP"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract numbers before `"GBP"`.

```
sub(".*?(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s?GBP", "\\1", df$item)
#[1] "226.80"   "2.80"     "2126.80"  "342.10"   "37654.90"
```

You might want to wrap this in `as.numeric`.

`.*?` means lazily capture as few characters as possible.

We are trying to capture information `(\\d+\\.\\d+)` which means a decimal number.

`\\s?GBP` means an optional whitespace followed by `GBP`, so that it also matches `226.80GBP` without a space if there are some cases.

---

To handle commas, without making any more complications to the regex, we can use `gsub` to remove commas completely from the string since the only information we need are the numbers so it does not matter if some other commas are replaced too.

```
sub(".*?(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s?GBP", "\\1", gsub(",","",df$item))
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. If it's not too much effort, would you be able to provide a little bit of expanded information on what the above line of code is doing, exactly? It's hard to parse at first glance.

Comment: @Simon Added some explanation.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, thank you. I have just found an edge case when applied to my actual data. Some long numbers aren't comma separated (e.g. 1654.80) whereas other can have commas (e.g. 1,654.80). Is there a way to handle commas in larger numbers?

Answer (score 2):

```
stringr::str_extract(df$item, "\\d+\\.?\\d*(?= GBP)")
# [1] "226.80"   "2.80"     "2126.80"  "342.10"   "37654.90"

# \\d+\\.?\\d* to match a number with potential decimal dot
# (?= GBP) is a lookahead for the " GBP" string
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the position is always the same. If that is the case then you can also you splitting methods. Here is an idea,

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(d5$item), ' '), function(i) tail(i, 2))[1,]
#[1] "226.80"   "2.80"     "2126.80"  "342.10"   "37654.90"
```

Of course you can also use the function `word` from `stringr` and simply do,

```
stringr::word(d5$item, -2)
#[1] "226.80"   "2.80"     "2126.80"  "342.10"   "37654.90"
```